# Split a json data into two separate jsons and add them in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a json file coming as:

```
{
              "rID": "1",
              "rFI": "01",
              "rTN": "0011",
              "rAN": "11",
              "sID": "2",
              "sFI": "004",
              "sTN": "1002",
              "sAN": "03402"
}
```

I am using Vue JS.

Currently if I have no API file, I am doing this as an array of objects in data as:

```
return 
rItems: [
                 { label: 'r', value: '01' },
                 { label: 'rFN', value: '001' },
                 { label: 'rTN', value: '00011' },
                 { label: 'rAN', value: '11255' }
            ],
             sItems: [
                 { label: 's', value: '01' },
                 { label: 'sFN', value: '001' },
                 { label: 'sTN', value: '00011' },
                 { label: 'sAN', value: '11255' }
             ],
```

and using a loop to display data, both `rItems` and `sItems` are in separate `divs`.

like this

```
<div class=" v-for="item in sItems">
                                <span class="label">
                                    {{ item.label}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="value">
                                    {{ item.value }}
                                </span>
                            </div>
```

same for `rItems` I have a separate `div`.

Now I have created an API file and I want this code to be computed so I can split the json into two and create an array of objects and loop over them.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Let me know if you want a full answer or you'd like to fiddle yourself with that.

Comment: if you show me how this can be achieved, that would be a great

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know how to fetch your data from your API, the final result would be something like this :

```js
const getDataAndSplit = async () => {
  const myData = await fetch(URL, etc etc); // get your data from your API
  const rItems = []; // declaring empty array to fill it later
  const sItems = []; // same
  // looping over array of key/values
  Object.entries(myData).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (val.startsWith('r'))
      rItems.push({label: key, value: val});
    else
      sItems.push({label: key, value: val});

  }
  return {rItems, sItems};
}
```

Comment: and this will put in computed

Comment: in my methods, i am already doing this;

`...mapActions('store', ['fetchBDetails']),
     

        fetchData() {
            this.fetchBDetails();
        }`

Comment: so all i need is to use the method in computed

Comment: please update your answer

Comment: I did. If it still doesn't help, then you will have to edit your question to be more precise and clear, as it isn't in this state.

Comment: ok, my concern is regarding this; 
const myData = await fetch(URL, etc etc); // get your data from your API

Comment: i do not ned to do a fetch because i have created a store and an api file to fetch the data from them and i have used the ...mapActions to to call filename and the action i created to fetch the data

Comment: the fetchBDetails is like this https://jsfiddle.net/gdjn12k4/